# jQuery function works on localhost but not on the web

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Really scratching my head on this one and couldn't find a related post anywhere. So I have a function on my website that when a user clicks their avatar two divs tog visibility using jQuery. The end result should look like this:

[image]

On my localhost everything works fine and I can see the animation but when I bring everything to the web it seems to break down and stop working right. I get this:

[image]

I tried to mess with the z-index, clearing my cache, and toggling visibility using dev tools but nothing worked.

I had a friend go to the site and try it out and the animation works fine for him and he gets the desired animation.

You can view the site here: http://infalliblegaming.com/

And btw when I click the avatar the animation goes all the way to the end but then seems to "pop up" into the navbar and is not visible by me on chrome. (if I inspect element on it though I can see the code)

username: aelo and password : aeloraelor

jQuery:

```
$("#avatar").click(function(){
     $("#avatarstats").stop().animate({
          width:'toggle',
          visibility:'toggle'
     });
     $("#avatardropdown").stop().animate({
          width:'toggle',
          visibility:'toggle'
     });
});
```

Comment: Where's the button to click?

Comment: Click the default avatar (the blue face after you sign in).

Comment: jQuery is a client side. Thus, it will not matter whether it's on your localhost or a public domain.
there must be something else. any console errors?

Comment: Could you give a test account then?

Comment: I can see the animation working fine for me.. for others you can login as username: aelo and password : aeloraelor

Comment: @mamdouh I don't get any errors.

Comment: @CT works just fine in latest Chrome and IE10 (after logging in), try clearing your cache?

Comment: I can see that it an issue where `.blogpostspaec` div is on top of `#avatardropdown`. Chrome Version 30.0.1599.69 (OS X 10.8.5)

Comment: @Kaarel I'm on Windows 8 and don't see that.
By the way guys I have tried this on (Windows 8) Chrome, Firefox, and IE, the only browser this happens on is Chrome. I have cleared my cache many times.

Comment: Could it be a cache problem ? Have your tried `Ctrl+F5` (force reload all resources) ?

Comment: @Robert I tried turning ad block off and it didn't work. LeGEC I tried that also and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main.css, try to change your blogspot class to position: block, or just remove the position attribute.

main.css, line 159

```
.blogpost {
    position: relative; (remove)
    background:white;
    border:1px solid #333;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 5px #333;
    max-height:500px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Observing the two screenshots, it seems that the first one was taken from a bigger screen.

Look this: [Screen](http://queryn.com/ss/Screenshot25.png)

Comment: Removing the position element allows the avatardropdown to be seen but it messes up other animations but I gave you the answer.

Comment: If your #avatarstats and #avatardropdown are fixed, you can try to move both divs to the end of the document and tweak the css. But I think your problem is not related with client/server, but with screen size. Try this: change the blogpost width to 700px, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with others animation on the same page? When nothing happens with animations the answer is that jquery is not correctly loaded. Be sure that you didn't link a local file on your server but link the script to

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

and for animations try include even this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps!

EDIT:1

Ok, i found the wrong way. Your **blogpostspace** divs are too much large if you put width=70%. On screen with resolutions like 1024 x 980 you find that 70% is much more than your avatar container fixed on the right. That's why you see the wrong borders going too much at right.

The solution is putting avatars element inside a div fixed on the right with dimension in % like:

```
<div id="container-avatar">
  <img id="avatar" src=.../>
  <div id="avatarstats">...</div>
  <div id="avatardropdown">...</div>
</div>
```

and style css lik this:

```
#container-avatar{
  position:fixed;
  width:20%;/* or whatever you want */
  right:20%;/* or whatever you want */
  top:50px; /* or whatever you want */

}

#avatarstats{
  position:relative;
width:70%;
float:left;
}

#avatardropdown{
  position:relative;
  width:30%;
  float:left;
}
```

This is the way i think by putting the avatar container responsive to browser width.

One advice, don't use

tags to define spaces between divs, just use margins to be sure it works ever.

Like:

```
<div class="margin-div"> bla bla bla .....</div>
<div class="margin-div"> bla bla bla .....</div>
<div class="margin-div"> bla bla bla .....</div>


css:

.margin-div{
margin-bottom:30px;
}
```

Bye!